# Django - create multiple elements of different model at once

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have 2 models with OneToOne relation between them. I want to create a single instance of each of them at once, to avoid 2 queries towards the server (which is a bit slower)

```
class FilePath(models.Model):
    storage_path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = ...


class Image(models.Model):
    path = models.OneToOneField(FilePath, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    width = models.IntegerField()

# I want these queries to be combined to a single server access
file_path = FilePath.objects.create(storage_path=r"/images/1234.jpg")
image = Image.objects.create(path=file_path, width=250)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bulk_create` function in Django is what you are looking for. This function takes an array as argument, the array contains the objects you want to save.

Example:

```
Image.objects.bulk_create([
    Image(path=gile_path, width=250),
    Image(path=gile_path, width=250),
    Image(path=gile_path, width=250),
])
```

for more info read the Django docs on this function. [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

Comment: Here I'm trying to create elements in 2 different tables